# how filled table in test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2

please help solve the problem.

model:

```
class StatusPoll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :polls
end

class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :status_poll
end
```

spec/factories/status_poll.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :status_poll_0 do
    id 0
    title 'open'
  end

  factory :status_poll_1 do
    id 1
    title 'closed'
  end  
end
```

spec/factories/poll.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :poll do
    association :status_poll_0
    sequence(:title){ |i| "title#{i}" }
    description Faker::Lorem.paragraph(7)
  end
end
```

i need fill table 'status_poll' follow values:

```
id: 0
title 'open'

id: 1
title: 'closed'
```

but after run specs in console i get follow error messages:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/phs $ rspec spec/models/poll_spec.rb
F...

Failures:

  1) Poll has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.create(:poll)).to be_valid
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant StatusPoll0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uninitialized constant StatusPoll0
```

You are getting this error because you don't have any class named `StatusPoll0`. Rather you have a class named `StatusPoll`. So, you have to specify the class for your factories.

In your `spec/factories/status_poll.rb`, specify the class of the factory as following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :status_poll_0, class: 'StatusPoll' do
    id 0
    title 'open'
  end

  factory :status_poll_1, class: 'StatusPoll' do
    id 1
    title 'closed'
  end  
end
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend the approach you're using.

Instead, create a general `status_poll` factory like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :status_poll do
  end
end
```

Then in your `poll` factory, create traits like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :poll do
    sequence(:title){ |i| "title#{i}" }
    description Faker::Lorem.paragraph(7)

    trait :poll_with_status_poll_0 do
      after :build, :create do |poll|
       status_poll = create :status_poll, id: 0, title: "open"
       poll.status_poll = status_poll
      end
    end

    trait :poll_with_status_poll_1 do
      after :build, :create do |poll|
       status_poll = create :status_poll, id: 1, title: "closed"
       poll.status_poll = status_poll
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your specs, you can build the traits like so:

```
let(:poll_with_status_poll_0) { create :poll, :poll_with_status_poll_0 }
let(:poll_with_status_poll_1) { create :poll, :poll_with_status_poll_1 }
```

You really want to try to model your factories to mirror your rails models. In your approach, you're generating factory models that do not represent real classes in your app.